# Wifi signal is intermittent on my laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I use my laptop Fujitsu lh 772 as my primary computer. I recently moved to a new apartment and the modem is too far away from my room so I used wifi instead. Everything seems fine at first, latency and speed from speedtest.com shows nothing suspicious (~17ms and ~23 Mbps), field strength is reasonable and I can browse website just fine, including HD videos streaming.

Problem arises when I recently use remote desktop connection to work from home. I realized there's (on average) a 1s pause every 5s during which my remote desktop won't responds to my command. The same thing happens during a video conference with my colleges. There's a 1s freeze for every 5s of smooth video call. The video call always resume after the brief freeze and my laptop shows that it was still connected to the wifi, no lost of connections whatsoever.

At first I thought the wifi is just not strong enough so I was planning on buying a repeater. But then one day I brought my other computer ( surface pro 3 ) back home and try to connect to my remote desktop with it on the SAME wifi, in the SAME room and the connection was as smooth as a wired connection! No pauses, my cursor was responsive, basically what people normally expect from a remote desktop connection. I then installed a remote desktop apps on my phone (galaxy s8) and the connection was also very smooth.

It is clear that there's something wrong with my laptop s wifi but I don't know what's wrong with it. Do any of you experience something similar? Can any of you give me some clues as to what's happening? What can I do to mitigate the situation? Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: Comparing different hardware is like comparing oranges with tomatos. What answer do you expect? Without data it's anyone's guess work. Please [edit]  and post the wifi devices you tested, except mobile. Maybe we can give a definite answer with that alone or maybe not as there are other factors to consider like antennae quality.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've managed to find the culprit and that's Samsung sidesync. Uninstalling it solved my problem.